# Android Studio Gradle 2.0.0-alpha1 build errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

Trying out the latest gradle 2.0.0-alpha1 build.
Gives me errors during compiling. I have absolutely no idea what is going wrong. 
Old gradle 1.5.0 is working without any issues.
Below is the output when i run ./gradlew assembleDebug -debug -stacktrace

```
task={from=abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, to=/Users/gillis/AndroidStudioProjects/FootballMania/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png},
latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false},
result=false}
12:07:42.224 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Task] Thread(png-cruncher_77): Process(784760824), after shutdown queue_size=0
12:07:42.224 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Task] Shutdown finished in 4689
12:07:42.225 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:mergeDebugResources'
12:07:42.225 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
12:07:42.225 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:mergeDebugResources (Thread[Task worker Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 9.416 secs.
12:07:42.225 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 12,5,main]] finished, busy: 4.182 secs, idle: 8.516 secs
12:07:42.226 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker,5,main]] finished, busy: 4.905 secs, idle: 7.799 secs
12:07:42.226 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker Thread 2,5,main]] finished, busy: 4.809 secs, idle: 7.892 secs
12:07:42.226 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker Thread 3,5,main]] finished, busy: 11.86 secs, idle: 0.834 secs
12:07:42.227 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
12:07:42.227 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
12:07:42.227 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
12:07:42.228 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
12:07:42.228 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
12:07:42.228 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
12:07:42.228 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
12:07:42.228 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
12:07:42.229 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
12:07:42.229 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
12:07:42.229 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
12:07:42.229 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
12:07:42.229 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
12:07:42.229 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
12:07:42.229 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
12:07:42.230 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
12:07:42.230 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
12:07:42.230 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
12:07:42.230 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
12:07:42.230 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
12:07:42.230 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:62)
12:07:42.230 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
12:07:42.230 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
12:07:42.231 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
12:07:42.231 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
12:07:42.231 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher.waitForAll(QueuedCruncher.java:260)
12:07:42.231 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher.end(QueuedCruncher.java:280)
12:07:42.231 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:132)
12:07:42.231 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:295)
12:07:42.231 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:400)
12:07:42.231 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:216)
12:07:42.231 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:88)
12:07:42.232 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
12:07:42.232 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
12:07:42.232 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
12:07:42.232 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
12:07:42.232 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
12:07:42.232 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
12:07:42.232 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
12:07:42.232 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 14 more
12:07:42.232 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
12:07:42.233 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
12:07:42.233 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
12:07:42.233 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
12:07:42.233 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 23.324 secs
```

Not sure what went wrong. Something with png files?
Anyone has an idea?
The output says something about log files. where are those log files?

this is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "x"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 301
        versionName "301.0"
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    lintOptions{
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        releaseAmazon {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
           // aidl.srcDirs = ['src/com']
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':holoduke_common')
    //compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile project(':gradientButtons')
    compile 'com.github.codechimp-org.apprater:library:1.0.+'
    //compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.+'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev148-1.20.0'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    //compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+@aar'
    compile project(':ASNE_facebook')
    compile project(':twitter')
    compile project(':vkontakte')
    compile project(':googleplus')
    compile project(':socketio_custom')
    compile 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.4'
}
```

Comment: okay ,set `buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'` and `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'` . Avoid `alpha1` version

Comment: Are you using gradle 2.8 ?

Comment: yes using gradle 2.8. its so frustrating. but thats why its alpha right :)

Comment: also i am getting AAPT: /Users/gillis/AndroidStudioProjects/FootballMania/app/res/drawable-ldpi/belldisabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file 
in my output. What is this error. I mean those files are for sure png files.

Comment: link to the google issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=195047#makechanges

Answer (score 2):

Try setting this in your **defaultConfig**:

```
aaptOptions.setProperty("cruncherEnabled", false)
```

Comment: the trade-off in this case would be increase in the apk size significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Recently,I met a similar problem.Maybe the same as yours.
Firstly,Let me tell you where is the log.
Just press the `Gradle Console` Button，see below.
[image]

If you can't find the button in the below of the AS Window,you can redisplay it in menu : `View - Tool Windows - Gradle Console`

Then build the project again,see the logs in the Gradle Console. If you have the same error log as mine which is 'Not a png file' you can check the png file ,the file may be not a valid png file. Correct it ,after another build you will success.
Hope this can help you .

Gook lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Use  gradle-2.10 and change the classpath `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2`.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation when I upgraded my Studio to 2.0.  This happens when there is a **corrupt PNG** file in your project as mentioned here [Android Studio Gradle build error :app:mergeDebugResources, Crunching Cruncher loader.png failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320765/android-studio-gradle-build-error-appmergedebugresources-crunching-cruncher-l/35480756#35480756)

Therefore, I used this tool http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html (for windows) and used it in command line as this **E:\PngCheck\pngcheck.exe *.png** for each folders where the .png files are and found a couple.  I then used the SnagIt converter to fix the .png file.

**Please keep in my that in my case the pngcheck is on E drive with the folder PngCheck.  Therefore make sure you just don't copy paste but use the right path for your pngcheck.exe file.**

Once this is done, I clean the Android project and everything went just fine.

Hope this helps...