# Exception : mergeDebugResources in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I got following Error if I try to add dependency in `Top - level` `build.gradle` file. This dependency is very much useful to add `GCM` in project without it GCM won't work:

Dependency :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

Error :-

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
```

If I remove that dependency from top-level build.gradle the project compiles and run successfully.

If I add that file I got the error and Android Studio do not run project.

Please help me to get out of this error.

**Edit**
Here is my project level build.gradle file:-

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta5'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try Changing latest version of dependency from [HERE](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/view):

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta5'
```

Also make sure you are setting correct Gradle plugin dependency as well in root project gradle file.

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta5'
```

So, your final project build.gradle file will look like

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta5'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta5'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried your code but it is not working. I got same error again :-(

Comment: please provide your full project level gradle file

Comment: I have solved the problem the problem is we have to make both tools and google-service version same. I have changed the google-service version to  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta2' and it solved my problem..

Comment: Good to see it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should help.

```
buildTypes {
       release {
     multiDexEnabled true;
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Gradle log, if you're getting bad/invalid PNG file then take a look at my answer at [Android Studio Gradle 2.0.0-alpha1 build errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892226/android-studio-gradle-2-0-0-alpha1-build-errors)

Hope this helps...